# Is there no way to serve a static directory and its children i Cherrypy?

Tags: python, cherrypy

Using Cherrypy version 3.0.2

Given a file-structure like this:

static-dir
  2011
  2010
  2009
   ...

I use the configuration: '/static': {'tools.staticdir.on': True, 'tools.staticdir.dir': 'static-dir'}

This works fine fore getting /static/anyfile

But if I try /static/2009/anyfile I get an error. I can add an entry in the configuration for this directory like: 
 '/static/2009': {'tools.staticdir.on': True, 'tools.staticdir.dir': 'static-dir/2009'}

This works, but it there no other way to serve sub-directory’s? Do I have to enter every directory under static-dir in then configuration to serve them?

Comment: Now I do get all the pages in sub-directory's using only the first line of configuration. Some typo when I tested it maybe. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to enter multiple entries; it should descend as far down as you need to. What error are you getting? 404? If you're using Cherrypy 3.2, try setting 'tools.staticdir.debug' to True.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure in CherryPY, but why not configure your front end webserver to serve static files? You really don't want that traffic hitting your framework.

Comment: In this case the site don't get a lot of traffic, and the most important pages are those dynamical created. Making those static pages available with one line of python code works better for me.